# check if git log returned any commits?

Tags: bash, git, boolean, return, return-value

Not used to bash scripting, but is there a way to add a flag to the end of "git log" so that I can get a return value for whether "git log" returned any commits or not?

Tried using something like git -log --exit-code, but this doesn't seem to be consistent.

Comment: Why not instead ask about a command that will exit with such exit code? Why _specifically_ `git log`? Do you want to check if there are commits between some `<revision-range>` _or_ do you want to check specifically if `git log` prints any commits?

Comment: i just want to check specifially if git log prints any commits

Comment: `git log` is a convenience command. For scripted queries use `git rev-list`, which has a `---count` option.

Comment: `git log` is one of the so-called "porcelain" commands, intended for human use but not necessarily programmatic use. Try the plumbing command `git rev-list --quiet` instead. (The exit status of `rev-list` doesn't seem to be explicitly documented, but the description of `--quiet` implies a non-zero exit status if no commits are found.)

Answer (score 0):

> i just want to check specifially if git log prints any commits

Just check if the output contains lines starting with `commit`.

```
git log | grep -q '^commit '
```

Comment: `git log --oneline | wc -l` ? [`git rev-list --count`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list#Documentation/git-rev-list.txt---count)?

Comment: The question is `i just want to check specifially if git log prints any commits` not how to check if there are commits. ;) The emphasis is on __prints__ - if git log __prints__ any commits.